# How To Automatically Submit Online From CSV Sheet On Schedule?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, excel, csv

I have a Wordpress blog and a simple PHP script that lets me create posts on the blog by uploading a `CSV` file.

To upload the file, I just go to the script installed on a subdomain, click `choose a file`, choose the `CSV file` and hit `send file`.

I want this to be done automatically, at regular intervals. For example, every 15 minutes it takes the next excel file in a directory and uploads it or better yet, it takes the next 50 lines of a csv file, uploads them and deletes them from the file.

Of course, I could try to rewrite the script itself to do this, but am looking for a simple solution. What is the most straightforward way of doing this? Javascript? An excel macro?

Comment: You need to setup cronjob for this.

Answer (score 0):

the following plugin has the option that makes you able to upload all your csv files and then you schedule the publishing time as you want

http://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/csv-2-post?filter=1